# onPressed does not execute Function even after using setState

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a function below

```
nextQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex++;
    });
    print('pressed');
  }
```

I then created the class below and passed in the method above a constructor for an onPressed property

```
class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final String answer;
  final VoidCallback? selectHandler;
  // ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
  const Answer({required this.answer, this.selectHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: selectHandler,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            answer,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I then used the constructor of the class and passed in the function to update the text on my screen which is in a list with **questionIndex** as its index

```
Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Question(question: questions[questionIndex]),
          Answer(selectHandler: nextQuestion(), answer: 'Yellow'),
          Answer(selectHandler: nextQuestion(), answer: 'Yellow'),
          Answer(selectHandler: nextQuestion(), answer: 'Yellow'),
        ],
      ),
```

This is not working/Is not updating the text on my screen after pressing the button

Comment: invoke your onPressed  like `()=> selectHandler`

Comment: Please  It is still not updating the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated the code and it works for me with a few exceptions:

1. Answer(selectHandler: nextQuestion(), answer: 'Yellow'), is wrong. You have to use selectHandler: nextQuestion (no () after the function)
2. Use the answer widget inside another stateful widget.

If you did all these and it still doesn't work run flutter clean followed by flutter pub get (close the debug session first)

And if that doesn't work, the problem is with your questions widget.